# How to pass Weblogic JMS maxmessage size argument in jnlp vm-args?

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, jnlp

My Jnlp file code is

```
<resources>
        <j2se version="1.6.0+" 
        java-vm-args="-PermSize=128m -MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=200000000 -Dweblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout=300" 
        initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="1024m" />
        <jar href="Example.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>
```

But,`-Dweblogic.MaxMessageSize=200000000 -Dweblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout=300"`
is not setting for weblogic...
Can you please help?

Comment: Solved: Please do it like ...........                          <property name="weblogic.MaxMessageSize" value="200000000"/>
    <property name="weblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout" value="300"/>
        <j2se version="1.6+" 
        java-vm-args="-XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" 
        initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="1024m" />
        <jar href="Example.jar" main="true"/>
    </resources>

Comment: You can mark that as an answer if you want so people know the question has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Please do it like ...........

`<property name="weblogic.MaxMessageSize" value="200000000"/> <property name="weblogic.CompleteMessageTimeout" value="300"/> <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" initial-heap-size="256m" max-heap-size="1024m" /> <jar href="Example.jar" main="true"/> </resources>`